# Trying to find Json Combinators under Play Java API

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I was looking at - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators
The above is under Play Scala API.
Is the same available under Play Java API?

I should be able to use gson? Any issues I may face or is this fine?
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

No, Play's JSON combinators are not available in Java, though you could write your combinators in Scala and call them from Java as needed.